# Why does predeclaring std::basic_string<T> break boost::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, compiler-errors, stdstring

Using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 compiler, with boost 1.53, I had some working code that used:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

Later I added the following two lines to a header file that was included before regex.hpp:

```
namespace std {template<class T> class basic_string<T>;}
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

Now I get a pile of compile errors, but if regex.hpp is included before these other lines, there are no errors.

The first few of many errors are:

```
c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\instances.hpp(106): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
19>          with
19>          [
19>              _Elem=char16_t,
19>              _Traits=std::char_traits<unsigned short>,
19>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char16_t>
19>          ]
19>c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\instances.hpp(106): error C2065: 'const_iterator' : undeclared identifier
19>c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\instances.hpp(106): error C2923: 'boost::match_results' : 'const_iterator' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'BidiIterator'
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
19>          c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\iterator_traits.hpp(116) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>' being compiled
19>          with
19>          [
19>              _Iter=int
19>          ]
19>          c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\match_results.hpp(68) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::re_detail::regex_iterator_traits<T>' being compiled
19>          with
19>          [
19>              T=int
19>          ]
19>          c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_53\boost\regex\v4\instances.hpp(106) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::match_results<BidiIterator>' being compiled
19>          with
19>          [
19>              BidiIterator=int
19>          ]
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator_category'
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
19>          with
19>          [
19>              _Iter=int
19>          ]
19>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category'
19>          with
19>          [
19>              _Iter=int
19>          ]
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
19>          with
19>          [
19>              _Iter=int
19>          ]
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(365): error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(365): error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(365): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value_type'
19>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(365): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
```

Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with my predeclaration of std::basic_string?

Comment: You're not allowed to add declarations to the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with my predeclaration of `std::basic_string`?

It has three template parameters:

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
    class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string;
```

But there's no reason to declare standard types yourself and, as you've demonstrated, a good reason not to. So don't do that; include the header if you need the declaration.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Mike, changing the predeclaration to this fixes the problem.  Nothing else had complained with my simplified predeclaration, but clearly regex does something odd.

Comment: @Coder_Dan: Please read the last line of the answer; perhaps I should have made it stand out more. There's no reason to declare standard types and, as your error demonstrates, good reasons not to. (And the regex header doesn't need to do anything odd; anything that includes both your declaration and the real declaration will fail).

Comment: Thanks @Mike - yeah I read that line.  I've questioned why this is on the other (near duplicate) answer, and explained why I've attempted to predeclare it.  I predeclare things regularly to reduce header dependencies.

Comment: On GCC 4.8 and 4.9 on an i7 3Ghz machine running under Mint 17 on a SATA3 SSD, just adding `#include <std::string>` adds 100ms to every compilation unit, 78 if it's in a PCH. On a small project with, say, 1200 files, that's nearly 2 minutes of compile time just for std::string.

Answer (score 7):

You've omitted a couple of template parameters from your declaration. The correct one looks like:

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
         class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string;
```

## Don't try to do this on your own though. Use `<string>`.

Comment: Not enough emphasis on the last sentence, +1

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, yes changing the predeclaration to this fixed the error.  Nothing else had complained about my simplified predeclaration, and I couldn't fathom how it could cause these error, but clearly it can.

Comment: What is the problem, by the way with predeclaring 'basic_string'?  We've only recently started using the standard library in a few of our source-files, so I was reluctant to spread knowledge of std::string throughout our source-base (just because I needed to add some methods that took std::string parameters in a commonly included header).

Comment: @Coder_Dan: One problem is that (at least up through C++03) the standard allowed an implementation to add still more template parameters, as long as they had default values. If an implementation took advantage of that, you'd run into the same problem again.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry.  That's intriguing.  I imagine that it's a big subject, dealing with multiple declarations of effectively the same template with varying numbers of template parameters.  When I wrote my predeclaration using only one template parameter, I wasn't sure whether the compiler would even accept the second declaration with more template parameters, but it did, until 'regex' scuppered it.

Comment: @Coder_Dan: *I was reluctant to spread knowledge of `std::string` throughout our code-base* That makes no sense at all. First, you need only include it in whichever component has the declaration, which incindentally is where it is needed. If that set is all the application, so be it. Second, `std::string` is a dependency on the *standard*, not a third party dependency. You are not introducing any dependency that was not there: a compiler, a library implementation... (unless you want to compile without the standard library, which is an option, but then you cannot use `std::string` at all!)

Comment: On GCC 4.8 and 4.9 on an i7 3Ghz machine running under Mint 17 on a SATA3 SSD, just adding `#include <std::string>` adds 100ms to every compilation unit, 78 if it's in a PCH. On a small project with, say, 1200 files, that's nearly 2 minutes of compile time just for std::string. On one project I worked on recently, we shaved nearly 35 minutes off full rebuild time *just* by predeclaring std::string.

Comment: @kfsone: Something sounds a bit off about seeing only a ~22% reduction in time from using a PCH.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Neither Bjarnes nor the GCC team seemed particularly surprised or concerned. I didn't benchmark Clang, MSVC or ICC (all of which we used) but they all saw similar rebuild time improvements +/-5 minutes.